# Replace certain digits representing year in date

Tags: r, tidyverse, data-cleaning

I am using a dbplyr package to tidy data from database table. I have a column with dates as below:

```
Date      
   <date>    
 1 6202-06-21
 2 6015-08-05
 3 5012-05-18
 4 3201-10-13
 5 3021-03-08
 6 3018-03-19
 7 3018-01-31
 8 3015-03-30
 9 3014-03-03
10 3013-05-31
# ... with more rows
```

The years are apparently wrong but only the first digit or two (depending on case) need to be replaced. How to accomplish it please?
I was trying to use the str_sub() in following way:

```
mutate(
    Date = str_sub((Date), 1, 2) <- "20"
)
```

I am getting this error message:

> Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42883: ERROR: function substr(date, integer, integer) does not exist;
> Error while preparing parameters   RROR: function substr(date, integer, integer) does not exist;

Comment: where did you get the years like that from? Check source. These might have been formated incorrectly with an incorrect origin. Given the correct origin, the dates might be correct

Answer (score 0):

A possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(
  Date = c("6202-06-21","6015-08-05",
           "5012-05-18","3201-10-13","3021-03-08","3018-03-19",
           "3018-01-31","3015-03-30","3014-03-03","3013-05-31")
)

df %>% 
  mutate(Date = str_replace(Date, "^\\d{2}", "20"))

#>          Date
#> 1  2002-06-21
#> 2  2015-08-05
#> 3  2012-05-18
#> 4  2001-10-13
#> 5  2021-03-08
#> 6  2018-03-19
#> 7  2018-01-31
#> 8  2015-03-30
#> 9  2014-03-03
#> 10 2013-05-31
```

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer but unfortunately it does not work for me.

Comment: Why? Could you please give details?

Comment: Thanks for a quick answer but unfortunately it does not work for me, I am getting errors:
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42601: ERROR: syntax error at or near "AS";
Error while preparing parameters   RROR: syntax error at or near "AS";

As mentioned, I am working on database tables, bringing them into R through dbplyr.
When converted to tibble, I am getting errors too:
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = mutate(Date = str_replace(Date, "^\\d{2}", "20"))`.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: The problem will be in the format of table, because I am able to reproduce your code  without errors, when it is a data frame from you example above. When I am working with data as tibble, or on remote db tables through dbplyr, I am getting errors in both cases

Comment: If you convert the dataframe to `tibble` (with `as_tibble`) _before_ applying my code, it works. Well, at least in my side.

Comment: Unfortunately it does not work for me. I am doing:

crz_top_contracts <- as_tibble(crz_top_contracts_db)


crz_top_contracts %>%
  mutate(
    mutate(Date = str_replace(Date, "^\\d{2}", "20"))
  ) 
I am getting errors:
Error in `mutate()`:
! Problem while computing `..1 = mutate(Date = str_replace(Date, "^\\d{2}", "20"))`.
Caused by error in `UseMethod()`:
! no applicable method for 'mutate' applied to an object of class "character"

Comment: Apologies, my mistake, now i see the problem.  Now its working when I convert it to tibble. Thank you very much for your help, highly appreciated

Comment: It is a bit pitty that it does not work on database tables, because I am working with a large dataset and converting it to tibble consumes huge resources... 
But anyway thanks once again..

Comment: I guess you do not need to convert to `tibble` -- you can apply my code directly to the data you get with `dbplyr`. Try that!

Comment: Unfortunately it doeas not working directly. When I apply your code:

crz_top_contracts_db %>%
  mutate(
    Date = str_replace(Date, "^\\d{2}", "20")
    ) 

I get error:
Error: nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 42883: ERROR: function regexp_replace(date, unknown, unknown) does not exist;
Error while preparing parameters   RROR: function regexp_replace(date, unknown, unknown) does not exist;
Note: the error message is longer, it exceeds the character limit so I cant paste it here all.

Comment: How do you get  `crz_top_contracts_db`? What code do you use?

Comment: This is how I am getting data  from database:
crz_contracts_full_db <- tbl(con_SK, in_schema("crz", "contracts")).
I am using DBI and odbc packages, db is Postrsql.
Then I get the table I am working on: 
crz_top_contracts_db <- crz_contracts_full_db %>%
  select( ....some code here)

Comment: Simply, do the following: `crz_top_contracts_db$Date = str_replace(crz_top_contracts_db$Date, "^\\d{2}", "20")`.

Comment: This code has no effect. It doesn´t produce any errors, but also it does not alter the date values.
But again it works well for data converted to tibble...

Comment: OK, I would try to avoid `dbplyr` -- that may be the culprit. You can read your table by using only SQL, via `DBI::dbGetQuery`